# SQL string gives me all posts with a category but not those without

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm running a Wordpress site, and I'm making a widget that gives me all posts that are the most read in the last 8 days.

When I run this SQL string I get all the posts with a category, but when a post isn't in a category, I don't get it.

How do I get all the posts that **ARE** in a category, **AND** all the posts that **AREN'T** in a category?

**My sql string**

```
$sql ="SELECT wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_content, wp_terms.name, wp_terms.slug, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID)
        WHERE (wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
           AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'readCount'
           AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
           AND DATE(wp_posts.post_date) >= '$eight_days_ago'
           AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
           GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
           ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC
           LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Maybe belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Comment: The database names ar not really clear.. Know when you `inner join` a post on a category. posts without a category wont be shown, you should use `left join` To dont lose these posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.  You need to change the joins to `left outer join`s and then check for `NULL` in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_content, wp_terms.name, wp_terms.slug, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID)
        WHERE ((wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category') or (wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy is NULL))
           AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'readCount'
           AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
           AND DATE(wp_posts.post_date) >= '$eight_days_ago'
           AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
           GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
           ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC
           LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the database, whatever it is, check for null in the category column:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_content, wp_terms.name, wp_terms.slug, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID)
        WHERE ((wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' OR wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy IS NULL)
           AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'readCount'
           AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
           AND DATE(wp_posts.post_date) >= '$eight_days_ago'
           AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
           GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
           ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC
           LIMIT 5
```

Comment: `WHERE ((wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' OR wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy IS NULL)`